# How to disable all FormControls inside a FormGroup

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I have this reactive Angular Form structure:

```js
myForm: FormGroup;
Personal: FormGroup;
FIRST_NAME: FormControl;
LAST_NAME: FormControl;
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createFormControls();
    this.createForm();
}
createFormControls() {
    this.FIRST_NAME = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
    this.LAST_NAME = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
}
createForm(): void {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
        Personal: this.fb.group({
            FIRST_NAME: this.FIRST_NAME,
            LAST_NAME: this.LAST_NAME,
        })
    })
}
```

If I do:

```js
this.FIRST_NAME.disable();
```

it disables the FormControl.

How to disable all FormControls in `Personal` FormGroup

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you want to disable the group, you need to tell what `this.Personal` is, now you have just declared it as a FormGroup, nothing else.

So you can do it **after** building the form:

```js
    this.Personal = this.myForm.get('Personal')
```

Then you can just disable it with:

```js
    this.Personal.disable();
```

DEMO: http://plnkr.co/edit/QAhY6A9950jqrgzvjVKu?p=preview

Comment: is there a way to default initialize a field group?

Comment: as in disabled or enabled

Comment: They way I see it, you can just do it after building a form if you want to disable it initially. http://plnkr.co/edit/h5ijJUl6qXJsYECgR0a3?p=preview

Comment: @AnkitRaonka as far as I can see, the only way to do it on initialization (make a form group disabled) is to initialize all the fields in that form group as disabled
`someNestedGroup: new formBuilder({
  email: [{ value: null, disabled: true }, [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
  ctrl2: { value: null, disabled: true }
})`  
When a form group has all of it's controls disabled, then the FormGroup itself is disabled

Comment: short and sweet ans. good work

Answer (score 20):

Given the following form:

```js
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  personal: this.fb.group({
    firstName: null,
    lastName: null
  })
});
```

**A)** If you want to programmatically enable/disable the `personal` form group, like the already accepted answer says, you can use `group.disable()` / `group.enable()`. However, I'd like to mention the importance of the options argument:

```js
this.myForm.get('personal').disable({ emitEvent: false });
this.myForm.get('personal').enable({ emitEvent: false });
```

The options argument `{ emitEvent: false }` is optional, of course. Sometimes you might want the form to emit the event, but sometimes you don't.
It is needed in case you do the toggling between disabled/enabled in a `myForm.valueChanges.subscribe()`, since sometimes you need to enable/disable different controls/groups based on the value/state of other controls in the very same form. Without `{ emitEvent: false }`, that will cause an endless loop.

**B)** If you want to make it disabled on initialization, then you need to initialize all of it's controls to be disabled. The following form group would be disabled from the start:

```js
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  personal: this.fb.group({
    firstName: [ { value: null, disabled: true }, Validators.required ],
    lastName: [ { value: null, disabled: true }, Validators.required ],
    email: [ { value: null, disabled: true }, [ Validators.required, Validators.email ] ],
    birthDate: { value: null, disabled: true }
  })
});

console.log(this.myForm.get('personal').disabled); // This will output "true"
```

I also added Validators as an example, in case anyone is wondering: we don't need to worry about validators when a control is disabled, the validation is ignored.

Comment: Best Answer this shape firstName: [ { value: null, disabled: true }, Validators.required ] is what i was looking for

Answer (score 13):

You can either disable whole form
`this.Personal.disable();`

or you can enumerate all form controls and disable/enable them one by one

```js
for (var control in this.Personal.controls) {
    this.Personal.controls[control].disable();
}
```

Comment: this.Personal.disable(); doesnt work  for nested FormGroup bt works for the whole form.

Answer (score 7):

A simple solution:

```
<fieldset [disabled]="!frmCheckout.get('id').value">
    ... All controls inside will apply disabled rules ...
</fieldset>
```

Comment: This is the best solution. short and clear, and it allows you to add custom styles to any control/element inside the fieldset. just add css query to find all input:disabled,
    textarea:disabled and etc.

Answer (score 6):

You can disable control like that. So your form builder should be like:

```js
createForm(): void {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
        Personal: this.fb.group({
            FIRST_NAME: {
                value: this.FIRST_NAME,
                disabled: true
            },
            LAST_NAME: this.LAST_NAME,
        })
    })
}
```

And then if you want to disable/enable. Use the following method:

```js
this.myForm.get('Personal.FIRST_NAME').disable();
this.myForm.get('Personal.FIRST_NAME').enable();
```

Answer (score 6):

you can disable all formControls like this :

```
    Object.keys(this.form.controls).forEach(ctrl => {
      this.editForm.controls[ctrl].disable();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enable/disable the FormGroup for example for editing data you can use this simple One-Liner:

```
this.Personal.disabled ? this.Personal.enable() : this.Personal.disable();
```

Comment: Why not just `this.Personal.disable()` ?